# global_step/sec and Examples/sec

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

What exactly do `global_step/sec` and `Examples/sec` means and what's the difference between them?

what happen if value passed by `tf.train.get_global_step()` does not increase?